# What port does Visual Studio use when I run a web application

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I have a web application project open in visual studio 2015 and I click run to view it in a web browser what port is Visual Studio using?

Thanks.

Comment: When you run your web application via visual studio it starts up iisexpress. You can see it in system tray. It allocates port number randomly to the application. You can see the port number in your browser localhost:xyz. xyz part is the port number.

Answer (score 0):

It should tell you. Either you check to see what port it's using in the localhost:xxxxx address or some configuration file for your project should have it in the settings.